# How does differential equations in the space of operator valued functions work?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

In my Quantum Mechanics class, we talked about Schrödinger Equation for the time evolution operator $\hat U(t)$,
$$i\hbar\frac{d\, \hat U(t)}{dt} = \hat H(t)\hat{U}(t),\qquad \hat U(0)=\mathrm{id},$$
with $\hat H(t)$ being some self adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, with the solution $\hat U(t)$ being some unitary operators.

And if $\hat H$ is independent of time, then we are given the solution
$$\hat U(t) = e^{-i\hat H t/\hbar}.$$
We were told to just plug in and check that this is a solution, and were given no further explanation.

I'm just basically not sure how most of this works. More specifically, I have the following questions.

1. How is the derivative defined? My guess is that, we are using the operator norm for the operator, and define the derivative the normal way?
2. If there's an integral, how is it defined? I've only seen lebesgue integral for real and complex valued function, and I couldn't think of a way it could work for operators.
3. How do we know that the solution $\hat U (t)$ will remain unitary, provided the only thing we know is $\hat H(t)$ is self adjoint and $\hat U(0) = \mathrm{id}$.
4. If $\hat H(t_1)$ commutes with $\hat H(t_2)$, is it true that the solution is $\hat U(t) = e^{-i\int \hat H(t) \,dt /\hbar}$? My intuition says this should be true, as $\hat U(t)$ should always commute with $\hat H(t)$ in this case.
5. How much does the theory of normal differential equation carries over? Do we know that the solution exist? Is it unique? etc. The most general differential equation I've seen is for smooth functions on manifolds, and the one here is obviously very different (the functions aren't even commutative).
6. What are some good references for these (if there are any)?

Note: I'm an undergraduate student double majoring in math and physics, and I have taken several graduate courses. So don't expect me to know any of the advanced results, but I'd love to learn about them :)

Comment: Have you read, and do you understand, the material in the Definition section of the [Schroedinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) Wikipedia page?  (That section has three subsections: Preliminaries, Time-dependent equation, and Time-independent equation.)  Do you understand that the unitarity of $\hat{U}$ encodes that it is a probability amplitude (a.k.a. wave) function on the Hilbert space?  Can you solve the equation for a *function* $\hat{U}(t)$? so that you have a formal solution?

Comment: Finally, do you see that complex phase is the only thing changing in that formal solution, so unitarity is preserved?

Comment: @EricTowers Please don't give suggestion when you don't even understand the questions. Here, $\hat U$ and $\hat H$ are the operators, not the wave functions.

Comment: You are overwhelmingly wrong that I don't understand the questions.  In addition, you would be overwhelmingly wrong to believe that I don't understand the correct ladder of abstractions to take someone asking your questions to this level of abstraction.  These questions are targeted to understand exactly where on that ladder you are since your questions indicate that you are confused about several of the rungs prior to the ones at the level of your class.

Comment: I agree with @Eric that you are overthinking it. For a constant Hamiltonian, you are instructed to consider seat-of-the-pants "matrix" exponentials, and formally solve the OD.  The operator extension of the mature theory of [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential)s and [matrix differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation)s is is normally *assumed* to generalize to QM operators, with some common sense.

Comment: @CosmasZachos The biggest issue is that the Hilbert space is infinite dimensional. Are there any references on the operator extensions of the theory? I'd love to see them.

Comment: Most physicists stay away from these things with extreme prejudice. I have no doubt there are such things, but you got to take a Reed-Simon-style course on functional analysis, not spatchcock books and questions together... I thought you just wanted to follow the course involved.

Comment: @CosmasZachos That's why I posted it on math SE instead of physics SE. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found some relevant information in the text [One-Parameter Semigroups for Linear Evolution Equations](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97696). I think it's only relevant for the case when $\hat H(t)$ is independent of time.

With some more reading, I believe the answer for question 1 and 2 is the Fréchet derivative and Bochner integral with the norm being the operator norm.

I wasn't able to find relevant information for time dependent $\hat H(t)$ though, and would love to see if anyone else can find anything.